# Dropdown resets all fields in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am currently working on a tasks app. Whenever I select the priority from the drop down or the date the values in the text fields above get resets to null, and also the selected date and priority are set back to default.

Would really like some help on the same.
Code snippet is below -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:ssms_new/Models/ToDoModel.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:date_time_picker/date_time_picker.dart';
import 'package:ssms_new/Tasks/AllTasksTabsView.dart';

import '../Configurations/configurations.dart';

class AddTaskModalSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTaskModalSheet({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AddTaskModalSheetState createState() => _AddTaskModalSheetState();
}

class _AddTaskModalSheetState extends State<AddTaskModalSheet> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final TextEditingController taskTitle = TextEditingController();
    final TextEditingController taskNotes = TextEditingController();

    String selectedPriority = "Normal";
    String _dueDate = "${DateTime.now().toString()}";

    Future<ToDoModel?> postNewTask() async {
      var response;
      String encodedPath = "task/new/$savedUserID";
      if (devMode == "development") {
        response = await http.post(Uri.parse('$devUrl$encodedPath'), body: {
          "name": taskTitle.text,
          "note": taskNotes.text,
          "title": taskTitle.text,
          "done": "0",
          "priority": "$selectedPriority",
          "due_date": "$_dueDate",
          "TaskOwner": "$savedUserID",
          "img": "NA",
          "studentId": "$savedUserID",
          "assignerId": "0",
          "closeTaskNotes": "NA",
        });
      } else {
        print(selectedPriority);
        response = await http.post(Uri.parse('$prodUrl$encodedPath'), body: {
          "name": taskTitle.text,
          "note": taskNotes.text,
          "title": taskTitle.text,
          "done": "0",
          "priority": "$selectedPriority",
          "due_date": "$_dueDate",
          "TaskOwner": "$savedUserID",
          "img": "NA",
          "studentId": "$savedUserID",
          "assignerId": "0",
          "closeTaskNotes": "NA",
        });
      }

      print(response.statusCode);
      String responseString = response.body;
      toDoFromJson(responseString);

      print(response.body);
      return null;
    }

    

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
              color: Color(0xff737373),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Column(children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Text(
                    "Add New Task",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        TextField(
                          controller: taskTitle,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Task Title",
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        TextField(
                          controller: taskNotes,
                          maxLines: 3,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Task Notes",
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 2),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4, right: 3),
                    width: screenWidth / 1.05,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 2),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                    child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                      items: priorityList.map((String category) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: category,
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(category),
                              ],
                            ));
                      }).toList(),
                      onTap: () =>
                          FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!.unfocus(),
                      onChanged: (newValue) {
                        // do other stuff with _category
                        selectedPriority = newValue.toString();
                      },
                      value: selectedPriority,
                    ),
                  ),
                  DateTimePicker(
                    type: DateTimePickerType.date,
                    dateMask: 'd MMM, yyyy',
                    initialValue: DateTime.now().toString(),
                    firstDate: DateTime.now(),
                    lastDate: DateTime(2100),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.event),
                    dateLabelText: 'Date',
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      _dueDate = val;
                    },
                    onSaved: (val) {
                      _dueDate = val!;
                    },
                  ), //Select Work Date
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  ElevatedButton(
                      style:
                          ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Color(0xffe9c46a)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        postNewTask();
                        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                          return AllTasksTabView(id: savedUserID);
                        }), (route) => true);
                      }, //TODO: add task here
                      child: Text("Add Task",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))),
                  SizedBox(height: 30),
                ]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the full widget code.

Comment: updated with full code.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing all your state inside the `build` method, so whenever the widget is rebuilt, all the state is overwritten.

Please take a look at [this tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive) to understand the difference between `StatefulWidget` and `StatelessWidget` and how to add interactivity/

Comment: i guess i was doing something wrong, i tried it again and it worked like a charm, thanks mate!!!